# How do I check if a TCP port is already being listened on?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, sockets, tcp

I have a third party library that acts as a HTTP server. I pass it an address and port, which it then uses to listen for incoming connections. This library listens in such a way that it doesn't receive exclusive usage of the port and address it's bound to. As a result, I can listen on the same port multiple times.

I need to run multiple instances of this HTTP server in the same process. Each instance has a default port, but if that port isn't available, it should use the next available port. This is where my problem is; I can end up with two HTTP servers listening on the same port.

I cannot change the HTTP server's code and the HTTP server will not alert me if it cannot listen on the port I give it, so I have to be able to check if a port is already in use before starting each HTTP server. I have tried checking if a port is already being listened on by binding my own socket with SO_REUSEADDR set to FALSE and SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE set to TRUE, but the bind and listen calls both succeed when an existing HTTP server is already listening on that port.

How is this HTTP server achieving this effect, and how can I accurately check if a port is being listened on in this manner?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use this particular HTTP server library? Given that it's broken, and you don't have enough control over it or even access to figure out what it's doing to make it work, switching would seem like a very good idea.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which library is it?

Comment: "This library listens in such a way that it doesn't receive exclusive usage of the port and address it's bound to". That is not possible in TCP. The only form of port-sharing that is possible in TCP is binding to different local IP addresses and the same port number. You need to re-investigate and then reformulate your question.

Comment: @EJP: If it's not possible, how is this happening? http://i.imgur.com/7ukBb.png I can reproduce this, regardless of what address I bind to.

Comment: @EJP: On Windows, it's perfectly possible for two TCP sockets to bind the same port. It's not _useful_ (the documentation explicitly says that the effects as undefined and non-deterministic), but it certainly can happen. (And it sounds like what the OP is trying to do is prevent it from happening, because it's not useful… although I admit I'm still a bit uncleaer on his exact intentions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quick and dirty method would be to try to `connect()` to the port on localhost.  If the `connect()` call succeeds, then you know the port is currently being listened on (by whomever received the connection).  If the connect call fails (in particular with `ECONNREFUSED`) then you can be pretty sure that nobody is listening on that port.

Of course, there's a race condition here:  Nothing is really stopping another program from swooping in and grabbing the port immediately after you ran the above test, but before you get around to binding to the port yourself.  So you should take the result of the test as more of a hint than an absolute rule, and (hopefully) have some way of handling it if you later find out that the port is in use after all.

Comment: His intended test code will have the exact same race condition (or, rather, would have the same race condition if it worked…). And really, there's no way to avoid it, given his design.

Comment: (The above is explaining why I gave you +1 despite the race condition, not disagreeing with your answer or anything like that.)

Comment: How about `bind`? If `bind` failed with that port, then it hasn't been bound.

Answer (score 3):

Use a port number of 0.   The OS will pick a free port.

Comment: I don't have access to the HTTP server's internal socket, so if I pass 0 as it's port, I can't get back the port the OS gave it.

Comment: Then bind a socket using port 0, use `getsockaddr` to discover the port number that was picked for you, initialise an HTTP server using the same port, and then close the temporary socket.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740621(v=vs.85).aspx explains how the different options interact.

You haven't given us nearly enough information to tell us exactly what's going on in your use case, but I can work through one arbitrary use case that would look like what you're seeing.

Let's say you're on Win 2003 or later, and your primary NIC is 10.0.0.1, and everything is running under the same user account.

The first instance of your app comes up, and your test code tries to bind 10.0.0.1:12345 with SO_EXCLUSIVEADDREUSE. Of course this works.

You close the socket, then tell the HTTP server to listen to port 12345. It binds 0.0.0.0:12345 with SO_REUSEADDR, which of course works.

Now a second instance of your app comes up, and your test code tries to bind 10.0.0.1:12345 with SO_EXCLUSIVEADDREUSE. According to the chart in the MSDN article, that works.

You close the socket, then tell the HTTP server to listen to port 12345. It binds 0.0.0.0:12345 with SO_REUSEADDR, which works.

If this is the problem, assuming you can't get the HTTP server to bind a specific address, you can solve things by using 0.0.0.0 in your test code. (Of course if it's one of the other hundreds of possible problems, that solution won't work.)

If you don't know what socket options, address, etc. the HTTP server is using, and don't have the source, just run it in the debugger and breakpoint the relevant calls.